# lvalue required as left operand of assignment in ios

Tags: ios, variable-assignment, lvalue, operand

Here is my code

```
[[X objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue] = ([[X objectAtIndex:i-1]doubleValue] * [[X objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue]);
```

Where X is array of double

Thanks

Comment: What's your question? Is that an error message? Also, please format your code.

Answer (score 2):

For setting value you have to use set method, something like this:

```
double d = [[X objectAtIndex:i-1] doubleValue] * [[X objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
[[X objectAtIndex:i] setDoubleValue:d];
```